# unity cinemachine smoothPath issue

Tags: unity-game-engine, cinemachine

I have an issue when I'm using cinemachine smoothpath component, I can create Waypoints and select them, but the bezier handler is not displaying someone knows how to display It.
BTW I'm using Unity 2019.4.22f1 and Cinemachine 2.6.3
Thanks in advance
[SmoothPath issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFOXN.png)

Comment: Is it supposed to "display" it? Otherwise I wouldn't call this an issue but rather a feature request ^^